# Selecting records where 'ActualLiveDate' is between today and X days in to the future with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the syntax to show a list of records where the `Actual Live Date` is equal to or greater than today by 7 days and ideally show how many per day (thursday = 7 records).

i was thinking something along the lines of:

```
SELECT [PW Number]
  ,[status]
  ,[install Date]
  ,[ICL Client Code]
  ,[Actual Live Date]
FROM 
   [QuoteBase].[dbo].[Circuits]
WHERE 
   [Actual Live Date] BETWEEN today and 7 days time  (this is where I am a little stuck as im fairly new)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need "today" to start at 00:01 this morning, then you need to remove the time portion from e.g. `GETDATE()`. I'm also using explicit functions to show that I'm adding days:

```
SELECT [PW Number]
  ,[status]
  ,[install Date]
  ,[ICL Client Code]
  ,[Actual Live Date]
FROM 
   [QuoteBase].[dbo].[Circuits]
WHERE 
   [Actual Live Date] BETWEEN
        DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE(),0) AND
        DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()+7,0)
```

If `Actual Live Date` contains a time component, you may want to adjust the `+7` to `+8`, depending on exactly which rows should be included in the result or not.

Comment: i accept this as the best fitting for my purpose as it gives me the next 7 days including today
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `BETWEEN` and `GETDATE()` functions for this, the `GETDATE() + 7` will add 7 days onto todays date

```
SELECT [PW Number]
  ,[status]
  ,[install Date]
  ,[ICL Client Code]
  ,[Actual Live Date]
FROM 
   [QuoteBase].[dbo].[Circuits]
WHERE 
   [Actual Live Date] BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 7
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column is actually a date, you need to be a bit careful:

```
[Actual Live Date] BETWEEN cast(GETDATE() as date) and cast(GETDATE() + 6 as date)
```

This would include today.  If today is a Monday, it would include seven days up to next Sunday.  If you would want next Monday too, then the `-6` would be `-7`.

When the column is a `date`, The comparison `[Actual Live Date] >= getdate()` will always be false for dates today because of the time component.

`Between` works as expected for `datetime` values but not for `date` values.